# How to generate address from an Extended Public key?

Tags: wallets, addresses, public-key

How can I generate a wallet address when given an Extended Public Key?

For example, an xpub key from Electrum?

I know this can be done with bitcoin and litecoin, is there a way to do it with Ethereum?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) does support HDWallet and let you calculate the address corresponding to an extended public key

```
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');

var extPubKey = 'xpub6ERoQFMqiUoTXAL56JpQYLq5FyXaZypJiKdsAbHKzMUQsSiJTNSMnBtYYRXxda9C6fUx6mMMqatUDNFSKxxXcpBcpPkTqVwyethpWiQN8p5';

var hdwallet = hdkey.fromExtendedKey(extPubKey);
var wallet = hdwallet.getWallet();
var address = wallet.getAddress();

console.log(`Address: 0x${address.toString('hex')}`);
```